# How to load each cookie file in a folder with pickle

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookies

In my cookies folder, there are many files cookies1.txt, cookies2.txt, ... and below is my script, I try to use it to login facebook with cookies, with each cookie file it will load and execute an action then finish and perform the next load file, it works fine when I run each cookie one by one but when I put them all in a folder, it appears an error, can someone help me? Thank you.

```
import os
import pickle
import selenium.webdriver


driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
files = os.listdir("cookies")
for f in files:
    cookies = pickle.load(open(f, "rb"))
    for cookie in cookies:
        driver.add_cookie(cookie)
        driver.get("http://www.facebook.com")
```

It shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tuong cat/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Lib/site-packages/new.py", line 10, in <module>
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)


  File "C:\Users\tuong cat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 894, in add_cookie
    self.execute(Command.ADD_COOKIE, {'cookie': cookie_dict})
  File "C:\Users\tuong cat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)


  File "C:\Users\tuong cat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidCookieDomainException: Message: Document is cookie-averse
```

Comment: How you get those cookies files?

Comment: @RatmirAsanov While you edit questions please don't add `<blockquotes`> to the error trace logs. Doing so debugging becomes difficult as the _error messages_ in the _error stack trace_  gets **word wrapped**.

Comment: @RatmirAsanov I use pickle to save cookies files .

Comment: But your files have `.txt`-extension...

Comment: I tried using .pkl and .txt, it works with both but when I put multiple cookies in a folder, it doesn't work

Comment: @ DebanjanB , I read your solution but I still don't understand, I pushed cookies to the right domain name, it's not another domain name

Comment: @vantuong You need to mark the contributors properly (`@` sign followed by _username_) while replying to them directly so that contributors are instantly notified (which you didn't :) ). Luckily I came back to it . Reopened.

Comment: @DebanjanB , how can I run it? I still don't understand your solution

Comment: @vantuong I need to see how you have _pushed cookies to the right domain name_

Comment: @DebanjanB ,I still don't understand how to push? I use the script above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to add the cookies after open the URL

```
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com")
for f in files:
    cookies = pickle.load(open(f, "rb"))
    for cookie in cookies:
        driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Your files of cookies should be with ".pkl" extension.

2) Your files should be generated by `pickle` package after login action with your creds for Facebook under your particular domain.

3) You should load cookies files under your particular domain.

In your case, particular domain is `facebook.com`.

Hope it helps you!

PS: Here is my working example for Facebook: [https://github.com/ratmirasanov/demo_test_automation_project/tree/master/login_with_using_cookies/](https://github.com/ratmirasanov/demo_test_automation_project/tree/master/login_with_using_cookies).

Comment: thanks , Ratmir Asanov ! It does not work with all 3

Comment: Maybe the problem in `http`? It should be `https`.